# Embed HTML-Content inside a tag?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently building a mail viewer in php. My server receive mails and store them as plaintext in a simple textfile.

Now I'm parsing the textfile and get the mail content as text and html (if provided). When i'm getting html, I stuck at the moment. I can't include them into my viewer to display the mail proper.

How do I include this html-mail-content which have tags like HTML, META, BODY, into my Viewer? I've tried several tags in my Viewer like DIV, OBJECT,... to embed the mail content, without success.

Comment: there's a lot of ifs and buts, so this is not a full fledged answer, but you could use an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a separate document. Create a separate php script that does nothing but output the mail contents (perhaps you need to pass it a message id?), then embed it into your viewer via an iframe.

```
<div class="viewer-container">
   <iframe src="/mail-viewer-script.php?message_id=123456"></iframe>
</div>
```

`mail-viewer-script.php`:

```
<?php

    $message = /* lookup message from GET parameter */

    echo $message['message'];
```

Once you get *that* done, you can start to worry about protecting your mail readers from XSS / CSRF attacks that may be sourced in the HTML mail messages.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.